# Angular.js - Why one root restriction with replace and how to get around it?

Tags: angularjs

Any Angular.js savvy person probably knows about this ...

[Angular.js Root Error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile%3atplrt)

My question is why and how do i get around this. When using tables it is not always possible to group the contents of your directive into a single parent element. So how do I get around this. I know ng-repeat does replace single elements with multiple, with out a parent wrapper, so it must be possible. What's the simplest way?

**-- UPDATE --**

Have ...

```
<td class="text-right">{{dsfgsdf.sdfgdsf.dsfg}}</td>
<td class="text-center">dsfgsdfg</td>
<td class="text-right">1500.00</td>
<td class="text-right">0.00</td>
<td class="text-right">2.51</td>
<td class="text-right">1502.51</td>
<td class="text-right">0.00</td>
<td class="text-center">-</td>
<td class="text-right">-1502.51</td>
<td class="text-right">-1502.51</td>
<td class="text-center">11/01/2013</td>
<td class="text-center">{{sdfg.sdfg}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{sdfg.sdfg}} - {{dfg.sdfg}}</td>
<td class="text-left">sdfgdsfg</td>
```

Want to add a directive ...

```
<td class="text-right">{{dsfgsdf.sdfgdsf.dsfg}}</td>
<td detailsDirective></td>
<td class="text-center">{{sdfg.sdfg}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{sdfg.sdfg}} - {{dfg.sdfg}}</td>
<td class="text-left">sdfgdsfg</td>
```

Comment: Please show an example of the directive template you are trying to use. :)

Comment: It's a general question, but added an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the general question of why angular directive templates are restricted to one root array, I'll refer to this text in the link to the error:

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
>   replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
>   is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
>   templateUrl must be contained within a single html element. For
>   example, `<p>blah <em>blah</em> blah</p>` instead of simply blah
>   `<em>blah</em>` blah. Otherwise, the replacement operation would result
>   in a single element (the directive) being replaced with multiple
>   elements or nodes, which is unsupported and not commonly needed in
>   practice.

Angular, in it's compile/link phases, needs to assign a hierarchical scope tree that corresponds to the DOM tree.  So, angular needs a single DOM element to hang a new scope for the directive off of.  That is essentially a limitation with how angular works. Therefore, the comment above that anything else is `unsupported`.

Comment: How does ng-repeat pull it off?

Comment: If you look at what ng-repeat produces, you can see that it is attaching to every element.

Comment: therefore, it is creating a scope for every repeat iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The single-root rule shouldn't make problems.  If you don't want a wrapping element (*span, for example*) inside your TD, you can use "replace:true" with your **detailsDirective**

`directive('detailsDirective', function() {

    return {

replace: true,

template: '<td></td>',  // wrapper`

Also,  See the **transclude** option, it can resolve your problem as well.
Otherwise, post here your directive's code.

Comment: <td detailsDirective></td> should be replaced by several <td>'s that can't be wrapped in anything as this is a table. How is the single-root rule not a problem here? I have replace as true. That is the problem, it needs a single root in the directive template when replace is true.

Comment: Also http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile, I am not so clear on what transclude does?

Comment: *"<td detailsDirective></td> should be replaced by several <td>'s"* - ok, I see...   so, why not use ng-repeat ?   **<td detailsDirective ng-repeat="">**

Comment: Because I want it to be in it's own directive with it's own link function that can do make calls and stuff.

Comment: In that case, maybe it shouldn't be in a directive.  but have the data array generated in the controller ?    the directive then purely used for "all the rest".         concrete code,  or more information would help to assist you better.